# Dirty electricity

Tags: electricity, damage

In the book "Elon Musk: Tesla, SpaceX, and the Quest for a Fantastic Future" by Ashlee Vance it is mentioned that at Elon's house there was a problem with "dirty electricity" that was causing devices to overheat.

I've experienced this in a variety of places with my own devices.

In one case, while traveling abroad, my devices would not work at one of my host's house it was so bad. In fact, his top of the line U.S. blender he had just purchased burnt out within 2 weeks. I didn't have this problem at all with my other host's house in the same country, so I know it's not simply a voltage conversion issue.

What exactly is "dirty electricity", what causes it and is there a simple way to prevent it from doing damage to your electronics while traveling or at home?

Comment: Read this link: http://www.emfields-solutions.com/howto/what-to-do-about-dirty-electricity.asp

Comment: That website is a huge pile of horse shit. Properly designed devices that are FCC/EU-EMC tested and rated emit little enough noise and are insensitive enough to not be bothered by it. Moreover 200mV of RMS noise is less than peanuts if measured over a broad spectrum. The whole site is all blither to sell useless crap people don't actually need. Just like magnets in your shoes and special carbon fibre mats to wrap around your water pipes.

Comment: Voltage across the world varies anywhere between 100V to 250V, and frequency is usually 50Hz to 60Hz. If you just use your devices on anywhere's electricity without paying close attention if it's capable of it, then you are screwing yourself from the beginning. Or, it might not be even legal to use non-locally certified devices at all, e.g. China has already banned universal power strips that is compatible for multiple country's plugs and "international adapter" has been a grey area since.

Comment: @Asmyldof I have had a feeling I could not express when seen this term for a first time (in this question in fact). You've done it for me, thanks.

Comment: I strongly advise you to take anyone who talks about "Dirty electricity" **not serious at all**. Since electricity is "mysterious" to many people, there are **charlatans** who take advantage of this. Fact is that they often know **nothing at all** about electricity themselves. They make the real engineers here cringe in anger for spreading fear, uncertainty and doubt. You'll never hear one EE say to another EE: "Look at this electricity, it is very dirty."

Comment: No, it can be a real problem in less developed countries. Power that is subject to voltage variations, surges and spikes can be described as "dirty".

Comment: +1 to what Asmlydof said. As soon as I saw their claims that dirty electricity causes physical ailments "including cancer, asthma, chronic fatigue syndrome, diabetes, ADD, autism and a number of neurological disorders" my bullshit detector went off. I would love to see actual valid, peer-reviewed papers or journals for any of these claims...

Comment: @pjc50 *can be described as "dirty".* - Yes, it can. But is it actually a valid technical term whose definition is unambiguous and matching yours?

Comment: As @Asmyldof said, that website is useless and not at all what I was looking for either. Aside from a clear explanation of potential causes, I really was hoping for something, preferably portable, that could sit between the source and my electronics to take the brunt of whatever was causing them to overheat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're travelling, take care to look at your electrical devices' specs. Electrical standards change the voltage and frequency of the mains. Just because it isn't a "voltage" issue, doesn't mean your blender won't burn up. The wrong frequency can burn out motors.

The main is supposed to supply a sinusoidal of a certain frequency, amplitude, and power factor, \$A*sin(\omega t + \phi)\$. Anything that deviates from this is a flaw.

Things can cause this to deviate from this ideal. Large motors can (strongly) affect \$\phi\$ (therefore changing the power factor) and introduce noise. Non-linear loads can cause harmonics.

Power factor will cause the resistive elements, like the wiring, to heat up (through \$I^{2}R\$) without contributing to work.

As to the blender: harmonics, if not filtered by the device, can burn out electrical motors.