# Physics of Dirty Electricity?

Tags: ac, dc, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, radiation

I've been reading about "dirty electricity" lately and while I know there's much controversy whether it causes adverse health effects this question is not about that subject. I'm simply trying to understand the facts and physics regarding "dirty electricity".

According to [GreenWave Filters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M6XNTO9) (which produce and sell filters to "remove" dirty electricity):

> Dirty electricity is erratic spikes/surges of energy traveling along
>   power lines and wiring where only standard 60Hz AC electricity should
>   be. It is created by electronics, energy-efficient lights, and many
>   other devices, as they manipulate electrical current to operate. Dirty
>   electricity can circulate throughout a building and to other
>   buildings, radiating potentially harmful EMFs as it goes.

**1)** What exactly is "dirty electricity"? Based on the above text, I understand that certain devices may draw electricity in aberrant ways causing it to spike/surge. What do we mean by electricity "surging"?

**2)** Do devices that generate "dirty electricity" contaminate all of the wiring in the wall? Or is it just around the outlet they draw power from? Or perhaps just around the device itself? If it does contaminate everything, how does the electricity from the device go back and contaminate the wiring in the whole house?

**3)** Most importantly, does this "dirty electricity" somehow radiate outside the walls (like WiFi) or is it something that just effects the flow of electricity in the wires? If it does radiate, does it radiate in a single frequency or multiple frequencies? Finally, does the amount of "radiation" depend on the amount of energy drawn by the device? Is there a way to measure it?

I understand it may seem like I'm asking several unrelated questions but I think all of my questions stem from a lack of understanding of the simple physics of dirty electricity. I think that if I understood exactly what dirty electricity is, all of my questions would be answered. This is why I'm asking it as one question.

P.S

I realize there are [other threads on stackexchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/do-compact-fluorescent-lamps-cfl-create-dirty-electricity-which-can-impact-hea) that address some of the health concerns related to "dirty electricity". Once again, my question is not related to health. I'm just trying to understand the physics of how it all works - what creates it, where does it exists etc. Also, [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331126/dirty-electricity) seems to address how dirty electricity effects electronics plugged into the wall but of course we are not plugging people into the outlet. So I'm trying to understand the physics of how it interacts with humans.

Comment: Those are all just words for unwanted radio waves and any current flow that changes over time (i.e. everything) will produce radio waves. The only difference is whether it's intentional by design (like a transmitter) or not.  They go everywhere and through everything, just like WiFi does. The only difference is WiFi is wanted. Devices that switch at high frequency will send noise down any wires connected to them, regardless of whether those wires are going into or out of the device and are ideally designed to minimize this.

Comment: You expect the voltages and currents on your AC lines to be perfect sinusoids. Anything that's not a perfect sinusoid is considered noise/dirtyiness. It should also be noted that a perfect sinusoid on it's own also produces radio waves just like all the "dirty" parts.

Comment: If you need "considerably clean" electricity, use a generously sized mains filter. If you need "100% clean" electricity, use a battery. Any other device won't help.

Comment: This is fake.  High power Wifi routers, Cell phones and  towers nearby transmit far more energy which increases with frequency for same power into dielectric cells.  The body does not absorb low frequencies by radiation at residential levels.  I recall an author who got a research grant in the 80’s convicted of fraud fudging the results

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93507/does-ac-current-produce-em-waves

Comment: The other term is for this effect is called harmonics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What exactly is "dirty electricity"?

This term isn't a technical one.

We might say a power line is dirty if its voltage doesn't vary according to the 50 or 60 Hz sinusoidal waveform we normally expect.

> I understand that certain devices may draw electricity in aberrant ways causing it to spike/surge. What do we mean by electricity "surging"?

It's normal (not aberrant) for some types of loads to draw current in frequent short bursts. If the device is not designed correctly, this current might need to travel along the mains wiring to reach the device.

But any device you buy from a reputable seller in a first world country should be tested for *conducted emissions*, which will limit the amount of quickly changing currents it can draw from the mains. Even if the device requires quickly changing currents internally, these can be delivered from capacitors inside the device rather than from the mains, if the device is well-designed.

> What do we mean by electricity "surging"?

A surge is a relatively long-lasting increase in voltage on the mains, compared to a "spike". A "spike" might last a few milliseconds. A "surge" might last for 100's or milliseconds or a few seconds.

> Do devices that generate "dirty electricity" contaminate all of the wiring in the wall?

As mentioned above, well-designed devices will not.

Also, even if they do, there will be no permanent "contaimination" of the wiring in the wall.

> Most importantly, does this "dirty electricity" somehow radiate outside the walls (like WiFi) or is it something that just effects the flow of electricity in the wires?

Rapidly changing voltages or currents can cause radiation in the form of radio waves.
Exactly how much they radiate depends on the frequency content of the voltage or current waves, the exact geometry of the wires, the presence of nearby conductive structures, etc., so it is not easily predictable.

> If it does radiate, does it radiate in a single frequency or multiple frequencies?

In whatever frequencies the voltage/current signals contain.

> Finally, does the amount of "radiation" depend on the amount of energy drawn by the device?

Not in any predictable way.

> Is there a way to measure it?

You could use an antenna and spectrum analyzer to measure whatever radio signals are present in a certain area.

Comment: As an additional point, to this excellent and specific answer, this radiation is certainly non-ionizing and so it's interaction with surrounding matter is limited to radio sensitive devices. Additionally this radiation has very poor coherence, so it's ability to deliver energy to matter that happens to have a resonance or absorption at that wavelength(s)  is very limited

Comment: @The Photon thanks for your informative answer. You mentioned that "any device you buy from a reputable seller in a first world country.. will limit the amount of quickly changing currents it can draw from the mains". Does this mean that a normal computer and Ethernet cable produce (at most) negligible amounts of dirty electricity? [This](https://www.emfanalysis.com/low-emf-internet-connection) and [this](https://www.emfanalysis.com/why-gigabit-routers-create-emi/) article claim to have measured EMI from your standard computer + ethernet cable. Do you agree with his conclusion?

Comment: They likely did read some EMI, a significant amount of engineering goes into making sure ther's a limited amount of EMI and that it doesn't cause other devices to malfunction or become unsafe.

Answer (score 11):

The language used by the sellers of this device is not particularly scientific. It appears likely to be a placebo device marketed to (self-described) sufferers of "[electrosensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_hypersensitivity)". There is no scientific basis for these claims, and this device is unlikely to have any real function. The advertisement and sale of such devices [has been prosecuted in some countries under false advertising laws](https://www.asa.org.uk/rulings/the-healthy-house-ltd-a13-248892.html).

There is some limited truth to the concept of "dirty electricity" *in relation to electrical devices*, but it bears little relation to what appears in the marketing information for this device. Most notably, it does not have effects on human health, and cannot be effectively filtered by a plug-in device of this nature.

Comment: I like the patience that The Photon provided in just marching through the questions. But I especially like the last dozen or so words of your answer -- which is exactly on the the mark for *this* product under discussion. The claims made and the plug-in nature of the device are fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: The claims made on the Amazon product page that the "cleaning" effects of this device can only be measured by a special meter conveniently made by the same manufacturer are particularly dubious. :)

Answer (score 2):

The old style flourescent lights, in which an arc has to re-strike at 120 Hertz, creates dirty (high-frequency content) energy on the local power lines. The fast risetimes of the arc, perhaps 10 microSeconds, (on scopes I've used, holding the scope probe tip up toward the tube some few feet above the lab bench) gets converted into radio waves by the wiring inductances and capacitances around the area, including all the way back to the power transformer.

IMHO in any system with sparks (motors) and arcs (flourescents) and rectifier diodes (any power supply), the area will be dirty, and the seeker of high-resolution measurements or of quality radio performance (AM and FM) or or wide dynamic range concert music, will have to use substantial filtering to prevent intrusion by the electro-magnetic "dirt".

Microwave ovens, rectifying 2,000 volt power using silicon diodes that quickly turn on under high-slew-rate conditions, are a fine "dirt-ier" of all around.